# Can not assert type of an object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaprogramming, python-2.x, metaclass

Why this source...

```
"""
[...]
"""
#   Import the standard date and time system.
from datetime import datetime as dt
#   Ommited the remaining imports section
class CuteClass(object):
    """
    [...]
    """
    def __init__(self, parameter_zero, date, parameter_two):
        """
        [...]
        """
        #   Omitted parameter_zero processing.
        print(type(date)) # FIXME delete this sentence.
        if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
            assert (type(date) == "<type 'datetime.datetime'>",
                    'assertion failed creating a CuteClass object')
        elif sys.version_info[0] == 3:
            assert (type(date) == "<class 'datetime.datetime'>",
                    'assertion failed creating a CuteClass object')
        else:
            sys.exit(inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe()))
        self.date = date
        #   Omitted remaining parameters' processing.
```

... yields for `python3`...

```
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
  File "...", line 37, in __init__
    assert type(date) == "<class 'datetime.datetime'>"
AssertionError
$ _
```

..? I want the class initializer be a harsh filter for object creation.

How do you deal with that? It all seems to be OK to me.

Comment: You are confusing the actual type object with its string representation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than comparing to `type` (which you certainly shouldn't do as a string!), use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance). Also, you shouldn't use `assert` like that, try something like:

```
if not isinstance(date, dt): # note you have aliased datetime.datetime
    raise TypeError(...)
```

Comment: The wisdom I was in need of.

Comment: To expand on jonrsharpe's comment: you should _not_ use `assert` to detect bad data in your program - use `if` or `try` for that. `assert` is for catching bugs in the logic of your program. A user shouldn't see an assertion error from your program merely because they've entered bad data. If the user see an assertion error it means that there's a bug in your logic and you need to fix the program for them.

Answer (score -2):

I asked the duck and then I told the duck I should do

```
        assert (str(type(date)) == "<class 'datetime.datetime'>",
                'assertion failed creating a CuteClass object')
```

instead of

```
        assert (type(date) == "<class 'datetime.datetime'>",
                'assertion failed creating a CuteClass object')
```

Comment: However, this is yielding 'SyntaxWarning: assertion is always true, perhaps remove parentheses?'. Never read that kind of warning until today.

Comment: And why did you tell this to the duck? A bit more explanation might be better.

Comment: I think the duck told you to do so. This may work, but is not at all a fine way dto go...

Comment: I meant I should have had the duck at the range of my hand, I forgot telling the duck before asking stack.